# Qtimer within a object doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm working with QT creator in a project and it seems like i'm stuck trying to get a QTimer to work.

I have a MainWindow object in which i can create and use QTimers without any problems. Within the MainWindow i create an object, wc, of a class called weightChanger. Within wc i want a timer that connects to several slots within wc.

I've tried a lot of different ways, but i can't seem to get the timers to connect. In my last try i tried declaring the timers in my header file for the weightChanger class:

[Picture of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUSoM.png)

Afterwards i initialize them in the constructor of wc and connects them aswell. I made a timerTest() slot which just sends a message to a console when executed, but i can't seem to get it working in any ways. I've tried several other ways of implementing the QTimer within the weightChanger class, but without any luck yet.

[CPP file for class weightChanger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DPSm.png)

Anyone got a hint to what i got wrong?

EDIT:

Here's my header file:

```
#ifndef WEIGHTCHANGER_H
#define WEIGHTCHANGER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include "ros_comm.h"
#include <rtl_msgs/target.h>
#include "user.h"


class weightChanger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit weightChanger(user* userTemp, const float &ctf, rtl_msgs::state *rtls, QObject *parent = nullptr);


signals:
    void targetForceChanged(float currentTargetForce);


public slots:
    void setRate(const float& ntf);
    void changeForce();
    void rangeOfMotion();
    void changePhase();
    void timerTest();


private:
    QTimer *weightChangeTimer;
    QTimer *changeWeightTimer;
   // rtl_msgs::target* rtlTargets;
    rtl_msgs::state *rtlStates;

    float top;
    float mid;
    float bottom;
    bool concentricPhase = true;

    float currentTargetForce;
    float newTargetForce;
    float rate;
    int numberOfRates = 8;
};

#endif // WEIGHTCHANGER_H
```

Here's my source file:

```
weightChanger::weightChanger(user *userTemp, const float &ctf, rtl_msgs::state *rtls, QObject *parent) :
    top(userTemp->getTop()),
    mid(userTemp->getMid()),
    bottom(userTemp->getBottom()),
    QObject(parent)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("weightchanger ros info work");
    rtlStates = rtls;
    currentTargetForce = ctf;
    weightChangeTimer = new QTimer(this);
    changeWeightTimer = new QTimer(this);
    weightChangeTimer->start(10);
    connect(weightChangeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerTest()));
    connect(weightChangeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(changePhase()));
    connect(weightChangeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(rangeOfMotion()));
    connect(changeWeightTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(changeForce()));
}

void weightChanger::timerTest()
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("timer works");
}

void weightChanger::setRate(const float &ntf)
{
    newTargetForce = ntf;
    rate = (newTargetForce - currentTargetForce) / 8;
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(rate);
    changeWeightTimer->start(10);
}

void weightChanger::changeForce()
{
    if(currentTargetForce != newTargetForce)
    {
        currentTargetForce =+ rate;
        emit targetForceChanged(currentTargetForce);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM(currentTargetForce);
    }
    else
    {
        changeWeightTimer->stop();
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("target force reached");
    }
}

void weightChanger::rangeOfMotion()
{
    float x;

    if(top - rtlStates->position >= mid)
    {
        x = (top - rtlStates->position)/(top - (mid + bottom));
    }
    else
    {
        x = (rtlStates->position - bottom)/((mid + bottom) - bottom);
    }
    emit targetForceChanged((currentTargetForce/2) * x + currentTargetForce);
}


void weightChanger::changePhase()
    {
        if(concentricPhase)
        {
            if(rtlStates->position <= top)
            {
                concentricPhase = false;
                setRate(50);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(rtlStates->position >= bottom)
            {
                concentricPhase = true;
                setRate(30);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first thing you got wrong were your screenshot code examples. Can you please post a complete class (header + source files)? Maybe do a dummy object just for this purpose, it might already help you with finding the root of the problem.

Comment: Try starting the timer after connecting to slots. In your CPP file i saw that your starting the timer first. Also other reason might be that the weightChanger object is a local object and it might be getting deleted as soon as it is getting out of scope, make sure you created weight changer object using new operator (on heap)

Comment: Try connecting the timer to only one slot at a time, and see if the problem persists. Create a dummy slot and connect to it and see if it works

Comment: @guru My problem was that i didn't create the weightChanger on heap! Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: @Christianv.S. You're Welcome :)